# Hibernate - how to generate id manually?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am working on data migration from one db to a new one in Java.
One of my issues are that I must keep the same id values of the entities.

I know it's possible to change the id generator, but I need to set the id manually.
Each entity I create using Map from old object to a new one and I just set values.
can't I just set manually something like:

```
Map<String, Object> newEntity = new HashMap<String, Object>()
newEntity.setId(oldEntity.get("id"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded in doing it.
In my entity I set the following:

```
@Id
private String id

private Date created
private Date modified

static mapping = {
    id column: 'id', generator: 'assigned'
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}
public Date getModified() {
    return modified;
}
public void setModified(Date modified) {
    this.modified = modified;
}
```

and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

map the values using mapobject.keyset() meathod in map and then process the values accordingly

```
     HashMap newmap = new HashMap();

      // populate hash map here you can assign your map values
     newmap.put(1, "tutorials");
     newmap.put(2, "point");
     newmap.put(3, "is best");

    // get keyset value from map
    Set keyset=newmap.keySet();

    // check key set values
    System.out.println("Key set values are: " + keyset);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it manually the way you described in your code.

But you need to make sure the new entity knows this.
If you only add the @Id annotation on your primary key (no @GeneratedValue, ...) and you make sure the database is also not auto generating an id it should work.

Comment: Thanks,
This is a Grails project using groovy and GORM
So which of the
@GeneratedValue should I use?

I set the private as:

 private String id

and then:
static mapping = {
  table 'dashboard'
  sheets column:'dashboardId',joinTable: false
  id column: 'id', generator: 'assigned'
 }

Comment: @TomerKfir I'm glad you found the solution. But in the solution you posted I would remove the:
asfsafas
sfasfsaf